# Functional Parser example from Programming in Haskell

Tags: parsing, haskell

On page 76 we define a function `item` as parser -- a function that takes a `String` and returns `[(Char, String)]` or `[]` if failed.

On page 78 we define a function `sat` that takes a predicate `p` and "wraps" a parser construction around that

```
p :: (Char -> Bool) -> Parser Char
sat p = do x <- item
           if p x then return x else failure
```

What I don't understand is the magic of `<-`? If the result of `item` is not empty then this operator should unwrap the list and fetch the first item from the tuple, otherwise it should produce something that won't choke the predicate. What am I missing?

Comment: It looks like you are using Graham Hutton's book "Programming in Haskell". Graham uses a simplification in this chapter that isn't strictly Haskell - see the closing remarks of the chapter (section 8.9) and the online code on Graham's web page for directly executable Haskell.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
do x <- item
   if p x then return x else failure
```

This is syntactic sugar for

```
item >>= (\x -> if p x then return x else failure)
```

`>>=` is the monadic bind operator.

What you're missing is: what is the definition of `>>=` for the `Parser` type? (Where in the book is the `Monad` instance for `Parser` defined? It will start `instance Monad Parser where`.)

Answer (score 1):

The `do` notation is desugared to applications of the monad operator `(>>=)`. More precisely, the definition of `sat` is desugared to the following definition.

```
sat p :: (Char -> Bool) -> Parser Char
sat p =
  item >>= \x -> if p x then return x else failure
```

The operator `(>>=)` first applies the `item` parser to the input. As you correctly observed this parser yields the first character. Then, `(>>=)` passes the result of the first parser to its second argument, that is, to the function `\x -> if p x then return x else failure`. This function checks whether the predicate is satisfied for the first character of the input stream. If it is satisfied, the function yields a parser (`return x`) that does not consume any input and simply yields `x` as result. If it does not satisfied the predicate, the function yields a parser that fails for any input (`failure`).